# How to integrate a complicated function?

Tags: matlab, integral

I have been trying to figure out this integral for some time, but have come up short. I have tried doing a symbolic integration, but I get it shot back out at me, so I am assuming there is not solution that way. I have resolved to solve it with a definite integral, but still keep getting errors:

```
clear
clc

x = 1;
y = 1;
z = 1;
R = 2;

b =@(theta) y.*cos(theta)/((x-R.*cos(theta)).^2+y.^2+(z - 
            R.*sin(theta)).^2).^(3/2)

integral(b,1,2)
```

My current error is:

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 515)
Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued
integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the division sign in the first term from `/` to `./` to ensure that you are doing [element-wise division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) and not [matrix right division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html):

```
b = @(theta) y.*cos(theta)./((x-R.*cos(theta)).^2+y.^2+(z - ...
             R.*sin(theta)).^2).^(3/2);
integral(b,1,2)

ans =

   0.055781612354862
```